# Windows 10 Touch Screen not responding

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

Have a Windows 10 laptop with a completely unresponsive touch screen.

It shows as active in the device manager and I have tried to perform the setup for the touch screen with no response to the input.

Unfortunately the end user doesn't know the actual time it stopped working (sometime around November at the earliest) so I am not certain if a specific update could be the cause.

Comment: Under `Win`+`X` -> `System`, what does it say next to `Pen and Touch:`?

Comment: Doesn't show anything special

Comment: Ok now it apparently thinks no drivers at all is the best driver software

Comment: But the device still shows up just without drivers?

Comment: Device shows up but driver details say none are loaded

Comment: In `Device Manager`, can you `double click` it, go to the `Details` tab, in the drop down choose `Hardware IDs` and give us the first line?

Comment: HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A107&REV_1813&COL01

Answer (score 0):

Following from the comments, it appears the driver is missing for the device.

The hardware ID `HID\VID_0EEF&PID_A107&REV_1813&COL01` indicates the driver is an eGalaxTouch.

Initially, the best idea is to look up the laptops model number on the manufacturers website for an available driver. I would recommend trying this first.

Second, I would just see if the driver is actually available on the machine but for some reason forgotten. Do this by going to `Device Manager`, `double click` the device, click the `Driver` tab, click `Update Driver` and choose `Search automatically for updated driver software`.

If these steps don't help, the driver download page for this device is [here](http://www.eeti.com.tw/drivers_Win.html). The first link for Windows 10, `For Surface Capacitive / Resistive / Surface Acoustic Wave / infrared.` should cover the device (and for some reason they provide a driver but don't recommend using it for Projected Capacitive technology). Ideally you should run the installer, but if this doesn't work, go back to `Update Driver`, choose `Browse for driver software` and point to the extracted folder.

Comment: Curiously the driver version does shows something and the driver date shows a date from 2006

Comment: @IG_42 likely a Microsoft default USB device, possibly a mouse or generic HID driver. They haven't changed them in a long time

Comment: So it's using a random driver for a different device to fill the space

Comment: @IG_42 Not necessarily - some touch interfaces are treated as a glorified mouse/graphics tablet interface. Did you have any luck installing a different driver?

Comment: So ran the installer, now it's "not connected" at all